# Hide background in image when using cropperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, crop

I found the following code [here](https://w3codegenerator.com/code-snippets/javascript/how-to-crop-multiple-images-with-cropper-js), and applied some minor changes to it.
What the code does is cropping multiple images with preview using cropper js in Bootstrap modal. (You can simply copy it to a `.html` file and open it in the browser to see):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crop multiple images with cropper js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    .g-height-50 {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .g-width-50 {
        width: 50px !important;
    }

    @media (min-width: 0){
        .g-pa-30 {
            padding: 2.14286rem !important;
        }
    }

    .g-bg-secondary {
        background-color: #fafafa !important;
    }

    .u-shadow-v18 {
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .g-color-gray-dark-v4 {
        color: #777 !important;
    }

    .g-font-size-12 {
        font-size: 0.85714rem !important;
    }

    .media-comment {
        margin-top:20px
    }
    .singleImageCanvasContainer{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 200px;
        width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-radius: .25rem;
    }

    .singleImageCanvasContainer .singleImageCanvasCloseBtn{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
    .singleImageCanvasContainer .singleImageCanvas{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<!-- code by w3codegenerator.com -->
<div class="container m-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="cropperModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Images</h4>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&amp;times;</button>
            </div>
            <form action="/upload-images" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="hidden" id="post_img_data" name="image_data_url">
            <div class="modal-body p-4">
                <div class="img-preview"></div>
                <div id="galleryImages"></div>
                <div id="cropper">
                    <canvas id="cropperImg" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
                    <button type="button" class="cropImageBtn btn btn-danger" style="display:none;" id="cropImageBtn">Crop</button>
                </div>
                <div id="imageValidate" class="text-danger"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.min.js" integrity="sha512-E4KfIuQAc9ZX6zW1IUJROqxrBqJXPuEcDKP6XesMdu2OV4LW7pj8+gkkyx2y646xEV7yxocPbaTtk2LQIJewXw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.min.css" integrity="sha512-Aix44jXZerxlqPbbSLJ03lEsUch9H/CmnNfWxShD6vJBbboR+rPdDXmKN+/QjISWT80D4wMjtM4Kx7+xkLVywQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").on("change", "#file", function(e){
            $('.singleImageCanvasContainer').remove();
            $('#post_img_data').val('');
        });
    })
</script>
<script>

    //Multiple image cropper and preview on creating post
    var c;
    var galleryImagesContainer = document.getElementById('galleryImages');
    var imageCropFileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    var cropperImageInitCanvas = document.getElementById('cropperImg');
    var cropImageButton = document.getElementById('cropImageBtn');
    // Crop Function On change
    function imagesPreview(input) {
        var cropper;
        //cropImageButton.className = 'show';
        var img = [];
        if (input.files.length) {
            var i = 0;
            var index = 0;
            for (let singleFile of input.files) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var blobUrl = event.target.result;
                    img.push(new Image());
                    img[i].onload = function(e) {
                        // Canvas Container
                        var singleCanvasImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
                        singleCanvasImageContainer.id = 'singleImageCanvasContainer'+index;
                        singleCanvasImageContainer.className = 'singleImageCanvasContainer';
                        // Canvas Close Btn
                        var singleCanvasImageCloseBtn = document.createElement('button');
                        var singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText = document.createTextNode('X');
                        // var singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText = document.createElement('i');
                        // singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText.className = 'fa fa-times';
                        singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.id = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn'+index;
                        singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.className = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn';
                        singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.classList.add("btn", "btn-sm");
                        singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.onclick = function() {
                            removeSingleCanvas(this)
                        };
                        singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText);
                        singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtn);
                        // Image Canvas
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.id = 'imageCanvas'+index;
                        canvas.className = 'imageCanvas singleImageCanvas';
                        canvas.width = e.currentTarget.width;
                        canvas.height = e.currentTarget.height;
                        canvas.onclick = function() { cropInit(canvas.id); };
                        singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(canvas)
                        // Canvas Context
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.drawImage(e.currentTarget,0,0);
                        // galleryImagesContainer.append(canvas);
                        galleryImagesContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageContainer);
                        // while (document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas').length == input.files.length) {
                        //     var allCanvasImages = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas')[0].getAttribute('id');
                        //     console.log(allCanvasImages);
                        //     //commented by sam
                        //     //cropInit(allCanvasImages);
                        //     break;
                        // };
                        urlConversion();
                        index++;
                };
                    img[i].src = blobUrl;
                    i++;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }

    imageCropFileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

        $('#cropperModal').modal('show');
        var mediaValidation = validatePostMedia(event.target.files);
        if(!mediaValidation){
            var $el = $('#file');
            $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
            $el.unwrap();
            return false;
        }

        $('#mediaPreview').empty();
        $('.singleImageCanvasContainer').remove();
        if(cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper){
            cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
            cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
            cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
            cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        imagesPreview(event.target);
    });
    // Initialize Cropper
    function cropInit(selector) {
        c = document.getElementById(selector);

        if(cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper){
            cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
        }
        var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
        for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
        c.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
        // c.id = croppedImg;
        var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
        var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        var image = cropperImageInitCanvas;
        image.width = c.width;
        image.height = c.height;
        var ctx = image.getContext('2d');
        ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);

        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            viewMode: 1,
            preview: '.img-preview',
            crop: function(event) {
                cropImageButton.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });

    }

    function image_crop() {
        if(cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper){
            var cropcanvas = cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                    width: 12500, height: 12500
                });
            // document.getElementById('cropImages').appendChild(cropcanvas);
            var ctx=cropcanvas.getContext('2d');
            var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cropcanvas.width, cropcanvas.height);
            // var image = document.getElementById(c);
            c.width = cropcanvas.width;
            c.height = cropcanvas.height;
            var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
            ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
            cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
            cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
            cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
            cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
            var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
            for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
                element.style.display = 'block';
            }
            urlConversion();
        } else {
            alert('Please select any Image you want to crop');
        }
    }
    cropImageButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        image_crop();
    });
    // Image Close/Remove
    function removeSingleCanvas(selector) {
        selector.parentNode.remove();
        urlConversion();
    }

    function urlConversion() {
        var allImageCanvas = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas');
        var convertedUrl = '';
        canvasLength = allImageCanvas.length;
        for (let element of allImageCanvas) {
            convertedUrl += element.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            convertedUrl += 'img_url';
        }
        document.getElementById('post_img_data').value = convertedUrl;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function validatePostMedia(files){

        $('#imageValidate').empty();
        let err = 0;
        let ResponseTxt = '';
        if(files.length > 10){
            err += 1;
            ResponseTxt += '<p> You can select maximum 10 files. </p>';
        }
        $(files).each(function(index, file) {
            if(file.size > 1048576*20){
                err +=  1;
                ResponseTxt += 'File : '+file.name + ' is greater than 20MB';
            }
        });

        if(err > 0){
            $('#imageValidate').html(ResponseTxt);
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, it works perfect for small images, the problem starts with large images (3000X3000/10 mega pixels or so), the background gets too long, this is how it looks:[image]

and I need to scroll down quite a bit to get to the image:
[image: ![enter image description here]

My question is how can I hide / cut this annoying background?

Comment: Are you ok with restricting the selection to only the image, or does the sample have to go outside the picture? If it doesn't, you can try restricting the view mode to something higher, or maybe even 4.

Comment: I tried this, it zooms too much into the image and doesn't show the whole image. Restricting the selection to only the image is what I'm looking for, but only as long as the whole image is seen.

Comment: @simon-sarris @niklas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added:

```
canvas{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

to the CSS and it fixed it.